# Cannot execute GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to return as `GROUP_CONCAT` 5 matches associated to the joined records, I tried to setup the query in the following way:

```
$sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT l.*,
t.name as team_name,
r.name AS rank_name,
r.color AS rank_color,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT m.* LIMIT 5, ORDER BY m.id) AS last_five_matches,
FROM league_ranking l
LEFT JOIN team t ON l.team_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN competition_ranks r ON l.rank = r.id
LEFT JOIN `match` m ON m.home_team_id = l.team_id OR m.away_team_id = l.team_id
WHERE l.round_id = :round_id AND m.status = 5");
```

as you can see I want return 5 matches which have the status = 5.

The problem's that I get:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* LIMIT 5, ORDER BY m.id) AS last_five_matches,
>       FROM league_ranking l

I don't understand where is the problem on the `GROUP_CONCAT`, notice that if I remove `GROUP_CONCAT` the query working, any help?

**UPDATE**

this is the query edited:

```
"SELECT l.*,
t.name as team_name,
r.name AS rank_name,
r.color AS rank_color,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT m.id ORDER BY m.id) AS last_five_matches
FROM league_ranking l
LEFT JOIN team t ON l.team_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN competition_ranks r ON l.rank = r.id
LEFT JOIN `match` m ON m.home_team_id = l.team_id OR m.away_team_id = l.team_id
WHERE l.round_id = :round_id AND m.status = 5
GROUP BY team_name"
```

and I get:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'swp.l.position' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Maybe you should get your query straight first. You are outer joining `team` and `competition_ranks`, because you expect to find `league_ranking` without team or rank? That doesn't seem to make much sense. You are outer joining `match` only to dismiss all outer joined records in your where clause? (`m.status = 5` dismisses those records, because in outer joined records the columns are null.) You want one aggregated row (by using `GROUP_CONCAT` without `GROUP BY`)? But what then are `team_name`, `rank_name` and `rank_color` supposed to contain? Or do you want an aggregation per team and rank?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner the last you said, I need an aggregation

Comment: As to `GROUP_CONCAT(... LIMIT ...)`: I don't think that's supported. It's not in the docs (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) at least, and were it supported, I'd expect the `LIMIT` to come after `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I discovered it's not supported, unfortunately I cannot get 5 records from `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: Okay. What do the tables represent? I'd expect each team to play in exactly one league and have one rank in it. This could be just two columns in the team table. But I see there is a league_ranking table. What does it represent? Can there be two entries in the table for the same team? Can a team have two different ranks? What is a rank exactly? I'd just expect rank #1, #2, etc., but you have a table with ranks and those ranks have names. Can you give examples?

Comment: your updated error is now duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql

Comment: And you want `GROUP_CONCAT` to show concatenated match IDs, say `'44,36,33,27,25'`? Are you sure?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner the rank isn't the position, a rank represent the competition ranking achieved by the team position. Suppose that a team with name Foo, will end the league in the first position, this team will achieve as rank the champions league qualification. Each rank give access to other competition for the next season based on the position achieved on the end of current season.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes, I need to return just 5 matches, because a team can play at least 40+ matches in a league, I just need the 5 recent matches which have as status 5 that represent "finished"

Comment: A team may have changed league and played two games in the new league. So you want to show these two games and the last three played in the old league? Or do you want two rows, one for the new league with two matches, one for the old league with five matches? And again: you really only want to show match IDs? It might be best you show some sample data and the expected result in your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
SELECT t.name as team_name, r.name AS rank_name, r.color AS rank_color,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT m.id ORDER BY m.id), ',', 5) AS last_five_matches
FROM team t LEFT JOIN
     league_ranking l
     ON l.team_id = t.id LEFT JOIN
     competition_ranks r
     ON l.rank = r.id LEFT JOIN
     `match` m
     ON m.home_team_id = l.team_id OR m.away_team_id = l.team_id
WHERE l.round_id = :round_id AND m.status = 5
GROUP BY t.name, r.name, r.color;
```

Notes:

- The `GROUP BY` keys exactly match the unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.
- I removed the `l.*`.  It doesn't make sense in the `GROUP BY` query.
- [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) doesn't support `LIMIT`.  Sounds like a good idea, but it doesn't exist.  Instead, form the list then take the first 5 elements.
- I change the `JOIN` order to start with `team`.  You seem to want one row per team, so that should be the first table in the `FROM`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) you can't use `LIMIT` statement with `GROUP_CONCAT()`. Try this one :

`.. GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT m.id, ORDER BY m.id) AS last_five_matches ..`

Comment: when I remove `LIMIT` I get: `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* ORDER BY m.id) AS last_five_matches,
    FROM league_ranking l
    LEFT JOIN' at line 5` and also in this way I don't take 5 matches but all the matches which have as status 5...

Comment: And replace `m.*` with a specific field like `m.id`.

Comment: okay, but now I get: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 5, ORDER BY m.id) AS last_five_matches,
    FROM league_ranking l
    LE' at line 5`

Comment: try without `LIMIT` and with a specific field

Answer (score 0):

GROUP_CONTACT is an [Aggregation Operation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html) which you need to have a GROUP BY clause describe under which values you are aggregating the records

```
SELECT l.*,
   t.name as team_name,
   r.name AS rank_name,
   r.color AS rank_color,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT m.<column_name> LIMIT 5, ORDER BY m.id) AS last_five_matches,
FROM league_ranking l
   LEFT JOIN team t ON l.team_id = t.id
   LEFT JOIN competition_ranks r ON l.rank = r.id
   LEFT JOIN `match` m ON m.home_team_id = l.team_id OR m.away_team_id = l.team_id
WHERE l.round_id = :round_id AND m.status = 5
GROUP BY team_name, rank_name, rank_color
```

Comment: with your query I get: `QLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* LIMIT 5, ORDER BY m.id) AS last_five_matches,
    FROM league_ranking l
    ' at line 5`

Comment: I have edited the code you need to specify the column which you need to concat

Comment: but if I need to get all the columns? I must write it manually?

Comment: Then you should concat those columns
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(m.x, "-", m.y, "-", m.z), ORDER BY m.id)